# GWT Expenses architecture

Tags: gwt, architecture

Why does the Expenses app from GWT SDK have the activities and views inside the same class? For example `com.google.gwt.sample.expenses.client.ExpenseReportList extends Composite` and `implements Activity`.

Isn't it best practice to separate these?

**UPDATE 2011.02.23:**

> From Google IO 2009 Ray Ryan's presentation, a reason for having MVP
>   is being able to make unit tests on the presenter easily without
>   involving code from the View. Since the Expenses app merged together
>   the View and the Presenter, the task of doing isolated controller
>   tests becomes very hard.

Comment: Anyone? Any idea? Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you think about testability of Expenses(see UPDATE 2011.02.23)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is. Because the view is a "heavy" object and should be cached and actvities can be created for every request for that view. This also has the advantage that state that is saved in the activity is flushed with every request.

Comment: I just saw the ROO generated scaffold. It separates the View classes from Activity classes. Could you please help me understand why 2 applications with 2 different practices? Which is best to follow? Thanks

Comment: any hints? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I would make the same if I would not like to reuse the view and it's components.

Answer (score 0):

Expenses ROO generated scaffold is a bit different. Dependency-injection GIN is used in there.
My biggest problem when applying places and activities best practices is to understand how can we reuse the views entirely since there are some components such as SuggestBox and CellBrowser that take as parameter in the constructor the model. The workaround I found is to use some sort of Adapter pattern for those UI classes. My bet is that they use one class for Activity and UI to overcome this. Would like to hear also what is the best practice to use such UI classes that are not thought to work with reusable views!